# Cannot find the symbol class R even after adding import com.example.app.R;

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-resources

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and i tried to build my android application and it was giving an error saying 'Cannot find the symbol class R' at all the places where I used R in the code. I already included 'import com.example.app.R' line in all the classes and the code is all correct and showing no errors. I also checked 
File->Project Structure->Modules and both gen and src are included as sources.
Help me fix this.

Comment: There's a possibility that one of your xml files has some sort of error. It prevents the R file from getting generated.

Comment: Like @ShivamVerma said there's possible an error with your xml files. Try to comment your new views added to your xml files and build again to see if there is an error

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing all of your code, but I suggest you try what akash89 posted below.

Comment: I checked all the .xml files there is no error in them beccause I have only two activities and in first one I added a button

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this way

File-> **Invalidat Caches/Restart** and then click on the **Invalidate and Restart** button.

Sometimes, it takes from the cache and screws up the operation, restarting and invalidating cache mostly works, please try out and inform.